# How to specify the reason when updating Subscriber status from API

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm updating subscriber status from API, and I want to specify Status change **reason**, to be able to retrieve it from `SubscriberStatusEvent` in the future.

Here is my code sample: .NET

```
var sub = new Subscriber
{
  SubscriberKey = subsKey,
  Status = SubscriberStatus.Unsubscribed,
  StatusSpecified = true,

};

soap.Update(new UpdateOptions
{
   RequestType = RequestType.Asynchronous,
   RequestTypeSpecified = true
}, new APIObject[] { sub }, out requestID, out overallStatus);
```

**How can I specify the reason field?**

**Is it OK to update the child busines unit level** subscriber, or should I use Top level business nunit for this?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to specify the unsubscribe reason that I am aware of is when using the LogUnsubEvent option with the Execute method:
http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call/

This method is different than updating a Subscriber object to have the Status property set to unsubscribe in that it generates a tracking event.  Since it generates a tracking event, it has to be associated with a specific email send (JobID) so it will not work if the Subscriber record has never been sent to.

As far as whether you want to updates the child business unit or the top-level, that would depend on the account setup.  Within the business unit configuration, there is an option under Unsubscribe Settings for "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this business unit only".  If that option is selected then it would matter where they were unsubscribed and that would be a business decision. If the other option "Subscribers will be unsubscribed from all business units in the Enterprise" then there is no difference. More info about this setting can be found at:
https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/enterprise/enterprise_20_overview/business_units/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should log the Unsubscribe event. Here there is a article explain how to do it:

http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/unsubscribing_and_logging_an_unsubevent_with_a_logunsubevent_execute_call/

The reason will be something related to API.

Do the update at child or at business level will depend on the Unsubscribe isolation you have configured at your BU (Unsub from BU will unsub from all enterprise or only from BU) or from the business needs.